# How to feed the output of a shell script to Prometheus and display it in Grafana dashboard?

Tags: kubernetes, prometheus, grafana

I wrote a shell script in my kubernetes cluster to give result of the total floating Ip count, no.of floating ips pinging and no. of floating ips not pinging. I need this data to be exported to prometheus grafana

This is the shell script:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

# Execute the `kubectl ko nbctl show` command and capture its output
kubectl_output=$(ip a)

# Use awk to extract the NATed IP addresses from the command output
nated_ips=($(echo "$kubectl_output" | awk -F'|' '$2 ~ /[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+/ {gsub(/ /, "", $2); print $2}'))

# Initialize variables to count successful and unsuccessful pings
success_count=0
fail_count=0

# Loop through the list of NATed IPs and ping each one
for ip in "${nated_ips[@]}"; do
    ping_result=$(ping -c 1 "$ip" 2>&1)
    if [[ $? -eq 0 ]]; then
        echo "$ip is reachable."
        ((success_count++))
    else
        echo "$ip is not reachable."
        ((fail_count++))
    fi
done

# Provide a summary message
echo "Out of ${#nated_ips[@]} IPs, $success_count are pinging successfully, and $fail_count are not pinging successfully."
```

I have no clue how to do it? I tried surfing on Prometheus official documents but none helpful

Comment: You either need a pushgateway or an exporter that supports textfile metrics, for example [node_exporter](https://github.com/prometheus/node_exporter#textfile-collector)